# max(value) returning 1 empty row on Postgres 9.3.5, works on 8.4

Tags: postgresql, max, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-8.4

I have a table with epoch values (one per minute, the epoch itself is in milliseconds) and temperatures.

```
select * from outdoor_temperature order by time desc;
     time      | value
---------------+-------
 1423385340000 |  31.6
 1423385280000 |  31.6
 1423385220000 |  31.7
 1423385160000 |  31.7
 1423385100000 |  31.7
 1423385040000 |  31.8
 1423384980000 |  31.8
 1423384920000 |  31.8
 1423384860000 |  31.8
 [...]
```

I want to get the highest single value in a given day, which I'm doing like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    outdoor_temperature
WHERE
    value = (
        SELECT max(value)
        FROM outdoor_temperature
        WHERE
            ((timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + (time::float/1000) * interval '1 second') at time zone 'Australia/Sydney')::date
            = '2015-02-05' at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
    )
    AND
    ((timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + (time::float/1000) * interval '1 second') at time zone 'Australia/Sydney')::date
    = '2015-02-05' at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

On my Linode, running CentOS 5 and Postgres 8.4, it returns perfectly (I get a single value, within that date, with the maximum temperature). On my MacBook Pro with Postgres 9.3.5, however, the exact same query against the exact same data doesn't return anything. I started simplifying everything to work out what was going wrong, and got to here:

```
 SELECT max(value)
 FROM outdoor_temperature
 WHERE
     ((timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + (time::float/1000) * interval '1 second') at time zone 'Australia/Sydney')::date
     = '2015-02-05' at time zone 'Australia/Sydney';
  max
 -----

 (1 row)
```

It's empty, and yet returning one row?!

My questions are:

Firstly, why is that query working against Postgres 8.4 and doing something different on 9.3.5?

Secondly, is there a much simpler way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I feel like there should be but if so I've not managed to work it out. This ultimately needs to work on Postgres 8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you're getting no results - you seem to simply miss data for this day.

But you really should use another query for selecting a date, as your query would not be able to use an index.

You should select like this:

```
select max(value) from outdoor_temperature where
  time>=extract(
    epoch from
      '2015-02-05'::timestamp at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
  )
  and
  time<extract(
    epoch from
      ('2015-02-05'::timestamp+'1 day'::interval) at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
  )
;
```

This is much simpler and this way your database would be able to use an index on `time`, which should be a primary key (with automatic index).

Comment: Bizarrely, that query gives me a single empty row on both Postgres 9.3 and 8.4! O_o

Comment: I should add that I've definitely confirmed that the data for that date is there!

Comment: It turns out I'm an idiot! Thanks for the simplified SQL, it works beautifully. :)